# What is the difference between !empty($data['name']) and $data['name'] != '' in PHP?

Tags: php

Can anybody please me what is the difference between these two statements in PHP?

```
if ($data['name'] != '')
{
  ...
}
```

and

```
if (!empty($data['name']))
{
  ...
}
```

When I replaced the first statement with second it fixes the undefined array element error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: zero is considered empty, as is false rather than just an empty string as you have above

Comment: check http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data['name'] !=` is called comparison, that's why it is called comparison operator.

`empty($data['name']` is checking either it contains data or not.

Doc: [PHP Comparison operations](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: That's… a… terrifically simplistic explanation…

Answer (score 1):

If you try to access a variable or array index *which does not exists*, PHP will warn you about this potential typo or incorrect logic with a `Notice`. If it's legitimate that you don't know whether the variable/index exists and you're trying to check precisely that, then use `empty` to suppress that notice.

`empty` is the same as `== false`, but does not raise notices in case of undefined variables/indices. Also see [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/).

Beyond that, look at the comparison tables for what comparison will yield what for the nuances between `== false` and `!= ''`: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php. The result will be different if `$data['name']` contains a `"0"` or `array()`. Those will be considered `empty` (`false`), but they don't equal `''`.

Answer (score 0):

- empty($data['name'] checks to see if a variable is empty. Empty is
  interpreted as: "" (an empty string), 0 (integer), 0.0 (float)`, "0"
  (string), NULL, FALSE, array() (an empty array), and "$var;" (a
  variable declared, but without a value in a class.
- $data['name'] != '' only checks if the respective data is not an
  empty string.